# Immutable.Js update gives error if Redux Devtools disabled

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, immutable.js, redux-devtools-extension

I have a strange problem. If **Redux DevTools** Extension is disabled on Chrome, `Redux Saga Reducer` gives an error. But when i enabled the **Redux DevTools** no error, everything works fine.

My client reported this problem because he hasn't Redux DevTools extension obviously.

This is the error when i disabled Redux DevTools :

> Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined

I am using redux-saga and immutable.js.
When an action finished with success or error it produces a notification with reducer. Reducers add new notification to `notifications` array and `Notify` component produces notifications.

**Initial state :**

```
export const initialState = fromJS({
    loading: false,
    notifications: [],
});
```

**Single Notification :**

```
{
    key: new Date().getTime() + Math.random(),
    show: true,
    type: 'success',
    message: action.request.message,
}
```

**Reducer :**

```
case FOLLOW_SUCCESS:
    return state
        .set('loading', false)
        .update('notifications', arr => arr.unshift(
            fromJS(
                {
                    key: new Date().getTime() + Math.random(),
                    show: true,
                    type: 'success',
                    message: action.request.message,
                 }
             )
        ))
```

How can i solve this **Redux DevTools** problem or what is this ?

Comment: i couldn't find a solution so removed Redux dev tools extension compose code from store creation for now and move initial state to root.